# EntryPointNotFoundException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am working on some other developer's code.

While getting data I called one method and got this exception

```
An exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in NDIP.Applications.ManagementConsole.UI.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Entry point was not found.
```

STACK TRACE

```
 at NDIP.Contracts.CMSInventoryMgmtService.IJITInventoryMgmt.GetScanCodeReportDetails()
   at NDIP.Applications.ManagementConsole.SiteManager.GetScancodeList() in f:\PROJECTS\ADP\RO\RST Order\Source\KRTService\AngularPrototype\JIT\Applications\WebManagement\ManagementConsole.UI\Components\SiteManager.cs:line 16
   at NDIP.Applications.ManagementConsole.UI.Controllers.ManagementServiceController.GetItemAliases() in f:\PROJECTS\ADP\RO\RST Order\Source\KRTService\AngularPrototype\JIT\Applications\WebManagement\ManagementConsole.UI\Controllers\ManagementServiceController.cs:line 71
   at NDIP.Applications.ManagementConsole.UI.Controllers.ManageSiteController.Index() in f:\PROJECTS\ADP\RO\RST Order\Source\KRTService\AngularPrototype\JIT\Applications\WebManagement\ManagementConsole.UI\Controllers\ManageSiteController.cs:line 27
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
```

CODE

```
public static List<ItemScancodes> GetScancodeList()
{
    IJITInventoryMgmt service = new InventoryService();
    ItemScancode[] itemaliases = service.GetScanCodeReportDetails();  // Error comes at this line

    //populate ItemScancodes
    List<ItemScancodes> list = new List<ItemScancodes>();

    foreach (ItemScancode info in itemaliases)
    {
        ItemScancodes scan = new ItemScancodes();

        scan.ItemIID = info.ItemIID;
        scan.ItemId = info.ItemId;
        scan.ItemClass = info.ItemClass;
        scan.ShipVendor = info.ShipVendor;
        scan.PackageQty = info.PackageQty;
        scan.UnitOfIssueCost = info.UnitOfIssueCost;
        scan.ItemGenericName = info.ItemGenericName;                
        scan.ItemAliasItemIID = info.ScanCode.ItemIID;
        scan.ItemAliasIID = info.ScanCode.ItemAliasIID;
        scan.ItemAlias = info.ScanCode.ItemAlias;
        scan.NDC = info.ScanCode.NDC;
        list.Add(scan);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Does that method use any native DLLs?

Comment: You called a controller method in the browser url and that gave you this error?

Comment: Non-.NET code - native code. Does the C# code use DllImport anywhere? (If not, that's not the problem...)

Comment: @JonSkeet : Yes it seems like it used NDIP.Services.InventoryService dll

Comment: As in there's a DllImport of that? Where? Please show the code.

Comment: @JonSkeet : any other information required ? any idea what the problem is?

Comment: @JonSkeet : I did not find any ``DllImport`` attribute in code. Dll are just referenced as we normally do using add reference.

Comment: I'm not sure why you previously said there *was* such a DLL then. Oh well...

Comment: Actually I misunderstood ``DllImport `` so I searched on google and found that ``DllImport `` is attribute used to include dll. But in my project it is not used anywhere

Comment: @JonSkeet As he said in the question, he's importing a dll of some other developer, whose variables he want to use.

Comment: This exception is raised generally with DLL imports, pinvoke

Comment: @JonSkeet  : any idea please

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla: It says he's working on another developer's code - I don't see how that stops the question of whether that code uses DllImport from being relevant...

Comment: @Gaurav123: Without more information, it's hard to say. I'd look at `IJITInventoryMgmt.GetScanCodeReportDetails` and see if there's anything unusual there... and check whether there's a nested exception anywhere to give you any more information. I'd also try to narrow this down by creating a short but complete console app that did *nothing* but demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet : thanks !!

Comment: @JonSkeet yes that's what I was thinking about, will be glad to see what u will come up with the test console app.

Comment: @JonSkeet : I come to know that we are replicating silverlight web application to angularjs application and Silverlight might use RIA services. I don't know why I am saying this, but hoping if you can get any idea from it then It will be fine.

Comment: No, that doesn't really help much. As I say, I'd try to radically reduce the amount of code involved to *just* a tiny example demonstrating the problem. At that point hopefully you can post *all* the code involved.